# Build tree from slash separated data

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have below data into my program.

```
 List<string> lstString = new List<string>();
 lstString.Add("a/b");
 lstString.Add("a/b/c");
 lstString.Add("p/a/b/c");
 lstString.Add("b/c");
 lstString.Add("a/b/c/d");
 lstString.Add("x/y");
 lstString.Add("x");
```

I want to build tree from above data(slash separated) like below.

```
a
--b
----c
------d
p
--a
----b
------c
b
--c
x
--y
```

then I want build one collection of class,

```
public class TreeNodes
{
   public int Level { get; set; }
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public int ParentId { get; set; }
   public string RootText { get; set; }
}
```

After filling the class collection, I want to generate a JSON string which represents the collection class "TreeNodes".

Can anyone help me out on this problem?